# QTDom - recursively add child to specific elements

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom, xml-parsing

I have few xml files, and some of it's nodes contains "reference" to each other. I want to add content of this xml as child to nodes, that contains this references

```
void GameObject::ExpandNode(QDomElement& expNode)
{

    if ((expNode.tagName() == "Instance" && expNode.attribute("type") == "library") ||
         (expNode.tagName() == "library" && expNode.hasAttribute("file")))
    {
        QString fileName;
        if (expNode.tagName() == "Instance" )
            fileName = FindLib(expNode.attribute("definition")).attribute("file");
        else
            fileName = expNode.attribute("file");
        QFile nestedFile(fileName);
        QDomDocument nestedLib;
        nestedLib.setContent(&nestedFile);
        QDomElement nestedNode = libDoc->createElement("NestedLibrary");
        nestedNode.setAttribute("path", fileName);
        nestedNode.appendChild(nestedLib);
        expNode.appendChild(nestedNode);
    }

    QDomNode childNode = expNode.firstChild();
    while (!childNode.isNull())
    {
        if (childNode.isElement())
            ExpandNode(childNode.toElement());
        childNode = childNode.nextSibling();
    }
}
```

But what i got is 
no matching function for call to 'GameObject::ExpandNode(QDomElement)'           ExpandNode(childNode.toElement());

How can i do this right?
                                             ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was wrong decision - to call ExpandNode, using temporary object. Solution is

```
QDomNode childNode = expNode.firstChild();
while (!childNode.isNull())
{
    if (childNode.isElement())
    {
        QDomElement childElem = childNode.toElement();
        ExpandNode(childElem);
    }
    childNode = childNode.nextSibling();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isElement : If this function returns true, it does not imply that this object is a QDomElement;

do this
    QDomElement node = childNode.toElement;
    if (node != NULL)
    {
       ExpandNode(node);
    }